# Network Status icon based on database value

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Hoping someone can point out where i'm going wrong.

I have a network status text & icon in the header/nav menu of my website that needs to update/change depending on the values provided in the DB - Notices table

In this instance the column in the DB is "SeverityLevel". This column has three values ranging from 1 - 3.
The code below should explain the rest, or at least what i'm trying to accomplish.

For reference the assests are: ok.png (Green circle), medium.png (orange circle), critical.png (red circle & text)

```
<?php
    $DBUserName = "*******";
    $DBPassword = "*******";
    $HostName = "*******";      
    $DB = mysqli_connect($HostName, $DBUserName, $DBPassword, '*******');
    
    //WE NEED TO SEE IF THERE ARE ANY OPEN NOTICES AND WHAT THE STATUS IS
    $GetNotices = "SELECT * FROM notices WHERE Status != 2 ORDER BY SeverityLevel DESC LIMIT 1";
    $GotNotices = mysqli_query($DB, $GetNotices);
    
    
    $FoundNoticesHeader = @mysqli_num_rows($GotNotices);
    if ($FoundNoticesHeader == 0)
    {
        //NO NOTICES
        $HeaderNoticeLabel = '<a href="#" target="_blank"  style="background: none; color: black"><img src="assets/img/ok.png" width=10 height=10> Network Status</a>'; 
    
    }
    else
    {
        //HAS NOTICES
        while ($Val = mysqli_fetch_array($GotNotices))
        {
            $HeaderPriority = $Val["SeverityLevel"];
        }
    
        if ($HeaderPriority == 1)
        {
            $HeaderNoticeLabel = '<a href="#" style="background: none; color: black"><img src="assets/img/medium.png" width=10 height=10> Network Status</a>';
        }
    
        else if ($HeaderPriority == 2)
        {
            $HeaderNoticeLabel = '<a href="#" target="_blank" style="background: none; color: black"><img src="assets/img/medium.png" width=10 height=10> Network Status</a>';
        }
    
        else if ($HeaderPriority == 3)
        {
            $HeaderNoticeLabel = '<a href="#" target="_blank" style="background: none; color: red"><img src="assets/img/criticial.png" width=10 height=10> Network Status</a>';
        }
        else
        {
            $HeaderNoticeLabel = '<a href="#" target="_blank" style="background: none; color: black"><img src="assets/img/medium.png" width=10 height=10> Network Status</a>';
    
        }
    }
?>
```

I've tried testing by changing the $FoundNoticesHeader to SeverityLevel 1, 2 and 3 but nothing seems to be workig the way i need it to and i can't for the life of me figure out where i'm going wrong. I'd really apprecite any feedback

Comment: The implementation looks as though it should do ... However if it does not (which is the only thing to indicate, you did not tell what that actually means _exactly_ ), then chances are that your SQL query fails. You did not implement _any_ form of error handling, so you are blind towards that situation. And interesting enough you prepended a "@" to the call to `mysqli_num_rows(...)` which suppresses an issue with that. For example if the query fails, which would assign the value `false` to `$GotNotices`. Which would lead to always the same result: the "ok" icon being shown ...

Comment: Are you actually outputting the value you assigned to `$HeaderNoticeLabel` anywhere ...?

Comment: Appreciate your comments and feedback. I did manage to resolve the issue. Thanks again!